# Cannot enable USB port when hub is plugged into adjacent port

Tags: usb

Here's my Current USB setup; I have an Anker branded powered hub connected to bus 3:

```
    lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 25, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 26, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 27, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 29, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

However, I get the following message to dmesg every second:

```
usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

If I unplug the hub that is on usb3, the messages stop.  My system is functional, but the messages make my dmesg logs grow fast and be harder to search.  What should I do to fix this.  I'm okay with disabling bus 4 if that's possible.

More information:

If I unplug everything from the hub, the messages still happen.

Kernel version:

```
Linux version 4.19.75 (nixbld@localhost) (gcc version 7.4.0 (GCC)) #1-NixOS SMP Sat Sep 21 05:17:15 UTC 2019
```

Comment: What is plugged into the USB hub?  Does it have a bad cable?  I'm not sure if `usb4` correlates to bus 4.  It looks like your hub is cabled into the 4th port of another hub that is in the 4th port of bus03.  That could be where the 4-4 comes from.

Comment: Also you mention adjacent port but it seems you actually meant to say bus.  Have you actually tried the USB hub on different physical ports?

Comment: @Jesse_b everything plugged into the USB hub is functioning properly.  1 Keyboard, 1 mouse, 1 sound device.  If usb4-port4 corresponds to Bus 3 Port 4, that would be quite annoying, but possible.